# Fulltext index query not working

Tags: php, mysql

Fulltext index is already set up on products table, however the query used below displays no results, it's giving an error

> Supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

To add, if I use the same query directly on database, it gives me proper results.

```
$kws = $_POST['kw'];
$kws = mysql_real_escape_string($kws);
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (product_name,brand,short_desc) AGAINST (".$kws.") limit 14" ;
$res_old = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res_old);
$i = 0;

if($count > 0)
{
echo "<ul style='list-style-type: none;'>";
echo "<li align='right' style='margin-right:20px;'><div style='border-bottom:1px solid #A5ACB2;'>Searching for $kws&nbsp&nbsp|<a href='search.php?search=$kws'>&nbsp&nbspSee All</a></div></li>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_old))
{
  echo "<li style='border-bottom: 1px solid #A5ACB2; padding:5px; margin-left:-40px;margin-right:5px;'>";
  }
And so on..
```

Any idea why is it happening? Code is continued from here & it's working perfectly fine if I use simple mysql query like this

```
select * from products where product_name like '%".$kws."%' or brand like '%".$kws."%' or short_desc like '%".$kws."%' limit 14
```

Anyone can help?

*EDIT*
$kws comes from a different php file, specifically from a text box. It's a search box in header & ajax is used for livesearch. This code is from livesearch.php file.

Comment: What is ft_min_word_len set ? And can u show the indexes for those columns ?

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions for connecting to mysql databases, they're deprecated, unmaintained, not garantueed to work properly with the current versions of MySQL and a potential security risk.  Also, you're using user input to build an SQL string.  You should never ever do that, especially not without validating and escaping the input first, you'll be wide open to SQL injection attacks otherwise.

Comment: `mysql_result` type is string however a resource is needed for `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I've not set ft_min_word_len anywhere. For creating indexes on those columns I used this particular query 'alter table products add fulltext (product_name,brand,short_desc)'

Comment: @GordonM Thanks for your advice, I will try to implement it.

Comment: hmm the reason I asked ft_min_word_len which is usually on /etc/mysql/my.cf in debian file and its by default 4 for any search with full text search done below string length 4 will return 0 rows.

Comment: @revo But it doesn't reach to while function, as I've used if($count>0), it makes no sense that any discrepancy between resource & string lies here, I think.

Comment: In which line error happens?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yeah that's hell right, and in fact mine seems to be 6, if I enter more than 6 characters, it works fine.

Comment: There u go !! You need to reset to a value. Restart mysql and then make sure to recreate the indexes after dropping them or do a repair table table_name quick :)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Again it seems to be a different issue, let's say my brand is 'xyz' so until I enter 'xyz' whole, it doesn't display any result.

Comment: Yes thats how it works it looks for full text (word) there different variant that could be used setting a wild card check here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,113504,113504

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I think I'm missing something here, fulltext searching is not working properly, I tried using directly on database. It doesn't display any result except a full length exact word.

Comment: Yeah I need partial search as well. Let me have a look at your link.

Comment: Okay, it worked fine. You can post an answer & I will accept it :)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty You haven't posted an answer.

Comment: ok let me post it I missed your last comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not work because of the word length being specified on  `ft_min_word_len`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

So in debian its usually `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

You need to set the min length there.

Make sure after resetting the word length to restart the mysql. In addition you may need to drop the indexes and rebuilt or repair the table.

More over there are different way you can use wild card on full text search. Check the following this might help you.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,113504,113504

Answer (score -1):

There's no evidence of any of the code you posted of anything that actually connects to the database (a mysql_connect() call).  Without that I can only assume you've not connected to the database.  You can't execute queries if you're not connected.

However I won't show you how to fix this because you're using deprecated mysql_* functions in your code.  You need to switch to mysqli or to PDO.  There are plenty of tutorials on how to use those libraries.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, then at least please explain why.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that if I use a different query, it works fine. It displays results & in fact I call dbconnect.php file in every php file, so connection is proper, if you can not make any comments due to mysql_* functions, that's fine.

Comment: If you're getting not a valid resource then you don't have an open connection.  If I can't see any code in your example that establishes a connection then I'm going to assume you forgot it.